# Installing more than one active variant using macports

Tags: wxwidgets, macports

I am using macports to install wxWidgets.  I would like both the release and debug version of the library installed  I used macports to install the release version by running `sudo port install wxwidgets`, and then used `sudo port install wxwidgets +debug` to install the debug variant.  When I run `port installed wxwidgets`, it shows them both installed, but only one of them is active.  When I run wx-config, it only shows the one that is marked as active.  Is there a way to get both release and debug as active so that wx-config knows about both variants at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't that get fixed with wxWidgets 2.9? Debug and release builds are the same?

Beyond that, or if you're on an earlier version, I REALLY suggest building wxWidgets yourself, once for debug and once for release. I used to have to build a ton of different variants (release, debug, unicode, and whatever combinations of those) and either hook wxconfig into my build process (like you're supposed to), or point my search paths at the right folder in my Xcode project.

Comment: I tried this on 2.9, and it appears to have the same issue.  I realize that I can build it from source, but I was hoping to use macports to do it for me.